# Approve Button in Mail should approve the record? Odoo v10

Tags: python, email, button, odoo-10

I am using Odoo 10. I am able to send the mail using python code. Now my requirement is to send two buttons approve and reject inside the mail. When user clicks approve button then the actual record in the database should approve. And reject button should also work in the same manner. How can I achieve this plz help. I tried below link

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-approve-a-record-through-email-120980
​

I want to know what we have to send in href of a button or link. Then how will it call the appropriate function in model or controller to do some task there. Actually I want to change the state of the record and send an email to the manager/user there.

Comment: what is the model of the record that you want to have this behavior for it?

Comment: Its a custom model. Working fine with approvals and emails. Now the requirement I got is managers should be able to approve with the button in their email notification

Comment: Did you send the mail or you still working on that,  if so please post the code I will try to help with this one because It's a nice requirement.